# how to change auto generate actionperformed in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, webview, javafx, fxml

i am new to javafx and i am now trying to make an actionperformed to call a class to view a webview in my application.

```
private void jMenuItem4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {}
```

I want to change java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt into javafx parameter so I can run action event from the javafx class, how do i change it?

```
 private void jMenuItem4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    final Stage stage = new Stage();
    final FXMLWebview fx = new FXMLWebview();

       Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
           public void run()
        {                           
               try {                                       
                   fx.start(stage);
               } catch (Exception ex) {
                   Logger.getLogger(MainMenu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
               }
        }
    });   

}
```

At first, i want to change the method parameter because I get and error from this code,like this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:237)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:400)
at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:212)
at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:198)
at com.mayora.gui.MainMenu.jMenuItem4ActionPerformed(MainMenu.java:476)
```

I assume that I am trying to run an javafx thread on awt thread..

Comment: You do know there's a difference between Swing and JavaFX?  There are also numerous examples of showing how to bridge JavaFX and Swing...As to your question, you can't, otherwise the `JMenuItem` won't be able to call the `ActionListener`

Comment: @mad programmer : I am still don't quite understand how to bridge javafx and swing, especially if using _webview_ , can you show me link that have a example so I can grasp a little understanding how to bridge them?

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm#CHDIEEJE) doesn't help?

Comment: I think I know where to start, I will read the article and try to understand to figure out what I should do later, thanks a lot !